# Firestore Recursive Delete via Firebase Admin SDK Local Node Server

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-admin

I'm building a Firebase Admin SDK local nodejs server to which I'm trying to add recursive delete functionality. The examples I've been able to find, such as:

https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/solutions/delete-collections

use firebase-functions and appear to require an auth token, which all seems applicable when using the Firebase SDK rather than the Firebase Admin SDK.

Here is my code, which I know isn't the way it can be done, but it hopefully conveys what I am attempting to do. Any leads would be greatly appreciated.

```js
const firebaseTools = require('firebase-tools');

async function recursiveDocumentDelete(fsDb, docRefPath) {
  const collRefPath = extractCollRefPath(docRefPath);
  const docId = extractDocId(docRefPath);
  try {
    const docToBeDeleted = await fsDb.collection(collRefPath).doc(docId).get();
    if (docToBeDeleted.exists) {
      recursiveDeleteFn = firebaseTools.functions().httpsCallable('recursiveDelete');
      const recursiveDeleteResponse = await recursiveDeleteFn({ path: docRefPath })
      console.log(`Document with ID ${docId} in the ${collRefPath} collection/subcollection, and all of its decendants, were successfully deleted at ${recursiveDeleteResponse.writeTime.toDate()}!`);
      return JSON.stringify(recursiveDeleteResponse);
    } else {
      console.log(`Document with ID ${docId} in the ${collRefPath} collection/subcollection was not found`);
    }
  } catch(err) {
    console.log(err);
  }
}
```

Comment: Also posted on https://www.reddit.com/r/Firebase/comments/cisbqq/how_do_i_implement_firestore_recursive_delete/

Comment: did you find a solution to this?